# Creating a vertical menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

Is this possible to create a menu [like this](https://www.volkswagen.fr/fr.html), (the left side fixed menu). When Height reduces the navigation shrinks.

I found a [sample form code pen](https://codepen.io/nikhil/pen/sicrK) but the collapsing not working here

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu-button").click(function(){
    $(".menu-bar").toggleClass( "open" );
  })
})
```

Comment: Share your code please?

Comment: Make a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) using your code so we can see where you're going wrong